# Hp cs10 wireless mouse (keyboard combo, but keyboard working ) not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, mouse, hp

I bought Hp cs10 wireless keyboard and wireless combo few months ago, works pretty well with windows 8. I installed Ubuntu 18.04  in Dell precision 3510, Keyboard works well but mouse is not detected. Flash on the Mouse is twinkling.

Comment: Flashing off and on when you are not using it?

Comment: @David , Yes Flashing on and off when not used and also during when I am try to use it

Answer (score 0):

If the lamp is flashing when not in use then the battery is most likely very weak. Try changing the batteries. At least that has been my many years of personal experience.

Comment: David, I think it's not the battery issue. Same mouse with battery unchanged works well in windows

Comment: Did you at least try changing the batteries?

Comment: Yes, its working

Comment: Please do the up arrow on my answer.